# How to convert from cborHex to VRFKeyHash using both cardanocli-js and cardano-serialization-lib?

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-serialization-lib, private-key, hash

I'm using `cardanocli-js` to create both VRF files for running a stake pool: `vrf.vkey` and `vrf.skey`:

```
const vrfKeyAccount = cardanocliJs.nodeKeyGenVRF("Totem");
```

Then I want to read the `vrf.vkey` file and convert the `cborHex` value to `VRFKeyHash` format, from the Cardano Serialization Lib. For that, I do:

```
CardanoWasm.VRFKeyHash.from_hex(JSON.parse(vrfKeyFile).cborHex);
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
/cardano-multiplatform-lib/rust/pkg/package/cardano_multiplatform_lib.js:16780
    throw takeObject(arg0);
    ^
JsValue("Deserialization failed in VRFKeyHash because: Invalid cbor: expected tuple 'hash length' of length 32 but got length Len(34).")
(Use `node --trace-uncaught ...` to show where the exception was thrown)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked that every cborHex on `vrf.vkey` files starts with the prefix "5820" and every cborHex on `vrf.skey` files starts with the prefix "5840". If I remove those prefixes from the conversion, then it works:

```
CardanoWasm.VRFKeyHash.from_hex(JSON.parse(vrfKeyFile).cborHex.substring(4)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help,

as **cborHex** is in **hex**, and you can pass a **Uint8Array** (bytes) to initialize a **VRFKeyHash** like in many *cardano-serialization-lib* objects, in theory you can use **Buffer.from(hexValue,"hex")**, like this:

```
CardanoWasm.VRFKeyHash.from_bytes(Buffer.from((JSON.parse(vrfKeyFile).cborHex,"hex")));
```

not tested!